# ANPR for XamarinFroms

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, automatic-license-plate-recognition, objective-sharpie

We are searching best ANPR (Automatic Number Plate Reader/Recognition) for Xamarin.Forms. I have already gone through **AnyLine** and **OpenAlpr**.

AnyLine seems to be high cost, based on image capture counts.

Regarding OpenAlpr we have a workable solution for [Xcode (IOS)](https://github.com/twelve17/openalpr-ios) and also [Xamarin.Android](https://github.com/kevinjpetersen/openalpr-xamarin).

The real problem is we couldn't bind the existing xcode project into xamarin.IOS using the **sharpie** tool (we tried sharpie for some other project, that works fine). Then we realized, that we can't create static library in xcode using an existing framework(*openalpr.framework*) files.

My question are,

1. Can we create static library using .framework file? please explain.
2. Else, Is there any other ANPR tools already available for Xamarin.Forms of Xamarin.IOS?

Answer (score -1):

MicroFocus IDOL has an excellent ANPR Solution which can be accessed via REST APIs. The product is called Media Server. 
https://www.microfocus.com/media/flyer/fast_and_comprehensive_vehicle_identification_flyer.pdf